# JavaScript - Send email using AWS SES

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email from my `alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca` email address, but I am receiving the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "statusCode": 400,
  "name": "InvalidParameterValue",
  "message": "The From ARN <alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca> is not a valid SES identity.",
  "code": "InvalidParameterValue"
  }
}
```

Both the from, and to email address show a `verified` status in the SES console and I have attached the following `Identity Policy` to the `alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca` email address:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "stmt1496992141256",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
        },
        "Action": [
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca"
    }
  ]
}
```

Yet when I run the following NodeJS code, I receive the above error:

```
Mail.send = function(email, cb) {
    var ses_mail = "From: 'AWS Tutorial Series' <" + email + ">\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "To: " + "alexdiv87@hotmail.com" + "\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Subject: AWS SES Attachment Example\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"NextPart\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "This is the body of the email.\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Type: text/plain;\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"attachment.txt\"\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "AWS Tutorial Series - Really cool file attachment!" + "\n\n";
    ses_mail = ses_mail + "--NextPart--";

    var params = {
        RawMessage: { /* required */
           Data: new Buffer(ses_mail) /* required */
        },
        Destinations: [
            email
        ],
        FromArn: 'alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca',
        ReturnPathArn: 'alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca',
        Source: 'alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca',
        SourceArn: 'alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca'
    };

    ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        else return cb(null, data);
    });
};
```

Aws docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [ARN in AWS space](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) means the whole resource name. This includes the following valid formats:

```
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resource
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resourcetype/resource
arn:partition:service:region:account-id:resourcetype:resource
```

and anything else is invalid. Therefore, your

```
FromArn: 'alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca',
```

would be:

```
FromArn: 'arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:identity/alex.divito@mountainviewwebtech.ca',
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely solved the error that i was getting. Afterwards, there was no error, but I was not receiving any emails still. I figured out that I had to add the `Identity Policy` to both email addresses (the sender and receiver). It appears that Amazon initially puts your account AWS account in a `sandbox` mode which disallows the ability to send emails to unverified emails. Until `sandbox` mode is lifted, you can only send emails between verified emails whom both have the `Identity Policy` attached to allow them to use SES.